# Link ruby to RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm

I tried looking for an answer for about an hour but no luck. I have installed `ruby-2.0.0` with my rvm but the system only detects the old `ruby-1.9.3` !I changed the sym link in `/usr/bin/ruby` to point to my `~/.rvm` ruby and now I get the following when I run `ruby -v`

```
ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24 revision 45167) [x86_64-linux]
```

However when I try to start a `rails server` I get the error which says my current ruby version is `1.9.3` I ran `gem env` and got a surprising results:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.23
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2012-04-20 patchlevel 194) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /var/lib/gems/1.9.1
     - /home/username/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "install" => "--no-rdoc --no-ri"
     - "update" => "--no-rdoc --no-ri"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

As you can see it is pointing to the wrong location. I tried modifying `.gemrc` to get it to work but it still refuses to change it's ruby installation directory. I have no idea how to fix it. I tried removing them all and starting fresh but apparently they are not installed via `apt-get` so I don't know how to remove them!

Any help will be very much appreciated.
Just for further info:

```
$ gem -v                                                    
1.8.23
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First list ruby versions in RVM

```
rvm list
```

For example mine says

```
   ruby-1.9.3-p484 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.1.0 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

To use a ruby version use command like

```
rvm use ruby-2.1.0
```

You can set default ruby like this

```
rvm use --default ruby-2.1.0
```

Now check your ruby version

```
ruby -v
```

### To ensure that non-interactive shells have access to RVM

Edit `.bashrc` using this command

```
sudo gedit /home/$USER/.bashrc
```

Make sure you have these lines there. If not add it.

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
[[ -s "/home/`whoami`/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "/home/`whoami`/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Now edit your .bash_profile using this command

```
sudo gedit /home/$USER/.bash_profile
```

Make sure you have these lines there. If not add it.

```
if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
  source $HOME/.bashrc
fi
```

Restart your terminal.

Comment: Thanks man you are a life saver. But I had to run my shell with `--login`  flag. When I try to use normal shell it is not using any of the ruby's on the `rvm list`. I have set the default but it's not using them. Do I have to reboot or I'm missing something else?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get rid of rvm completely, use the command

```
rvm implode
```

But apart from that, once you install ruby `2.0.0` using rvm, are you using it also? Use the command

```
rvm use 2.0.0
```

and that should set it. To check which ruby is being used, try the command

```
which ruby
```