# Having trouble installing Ruby 2.1.1

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, terminal, rbenv

I am trying to update my Ruby version with my rbenv and am having trouble installing 2.1.1. I have followed the instructions carefully but it does not seem to be working for some reason. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

```
Installed ruby-2.1.1 to /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1  
$ 
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
$ rbenv rehash
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
$ rbenv global 2.1.1
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
$ rbenv global 2.1.1
$ rbenv rehash
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
$ rbenv local 2.1.1
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
$ rbenv versions
system
* 2.1.1 (set by /Users/user/.ruby-version)
$ rbenv global 2.1.1
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
$
```

Any thoughts on what's going on?

not sure if this helps get to the root of the issue..

```
PATH=usr/local/bin:/urs/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:usr/local/bin:/urs/local/sbin:/usr/loca        /mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
\$ ~/.bash_profile
-bash: /Users/user/.bash_profile: Permission denied
$ ~/.bash_profile
-bash: /Users/user/.bash_profile: Permission denied
$ export PATH="$HOME./rbenv/bin:$PATH"
$ "$(rbenv init -)"
-bash: export PATH="/Users/user/.rbenv/shims:${PATH}"
source "/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/libexec/../completions/rbenv.bash"
rbenv rehash 2>/dev/null
rbenv() {
typeset command
command="$1"
if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
shift
fi

case "$command" in
rehash|shell)
eval `rbenv "sh-$command" "$@"`;;
*)
command rbenv "$command" "$@";;
esac
}: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Can you do a `which ruby` and tell us the output?

Comment: $ which ruby
    /usr/bin/ruby

Comment: Have a look at this answer and see if that helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12150580/1466095

Comment: doesn't really help but I did paste some more info into my original post @SampritiPanda

Comment: @keepcoding Actually I've tried to install rbenv in my ubuntu 12.04. I couldn't make it work properly. so I switched to rvm. I highly recommend rvm. I even posted steps today. http://stackoverflow.com/a/22418096/736037

Comment: @keepcoding I guess you are using windows. so never mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sigh... first, take a close look at your path:

```
PATH=usr/local/bin:/urs/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:usr/local/bin:/urs/local/sbin:/usr/loca        /mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

You have multiple definitions for the same directories, and, in addition have what are very likely  invalid directory names:

- `usr/local/bin` should be `/usr/local/bin`. `usr/local/bin` is a relative directory name, which would usually be invalid anywhere unless you're in your `/` directory. This is in the path multiple times, so remove all but the middle one and fix the name.
- `/urs/local/sbin` is probably a misspelled directory `/usr/local/sbin`, but, at the same time, you probably shouldn't have a `.../sbin` directory in your path because you'll seldom use the files in there. That particular directory is in your path twice, so remove at least one.
- `/usr/loca        /mysql/bin` is totally invalid so remove it. If you are using MySQL, then fix that entry; It's probably `/usr/local/share/mysql/bin`, but confirm that and adjust as necessary.

You're using

```
export PATH="$HOME./rbenv/bin:$PATH"
```

which is not a valid definition for PATH. `$HOME` would normally look like `/home/user`, without a terminating or delimiting `/`. Using `$HOME./rbenv...` would result in `/home/user./rbenv...` which isn't valid.

rbenv needs a chance to initialize when your shell session starts. To do that it expects you to add

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

to your ~/.bash_profile file as the very last lines. It's obvious that hasn't been done because your path would reflect that if it had. Mine starts with a reference to rbenv's shim, then bin directories.

> I have followed the instructions carefully but it does not seem to be working for some reason.

I'd *strongly* recommend you [read the rbenv documentation](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#how-it-works) for setting it up.

Comment: Just be careful messing with the path. A simple slip and you can make it so your machine won't find anything when you're at the command prompt, and, if you don't know your way around (which I suspect is true because of the mistakes you made) you'll have a really hard time getting it fixed.